# Flex Singleton Solution

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, singleton

When we implement Singleton class, the constructor in flex can't be private, so that other class still can new that Singleton Class. I found a solution to implement the Singleton class with a "private" constructor:

```
package
{
    public class Singleton
    {
        public static function get Instance():SingletonPrivate
        {
            return SingletonPrivate.Instance;
        }
    }
}
class SingletonPrivate
{
    public static const Instance:SingletonPrivate = new SingletonPrivate();
    public function SingletonPrivate()
    {       

    }

    public function getValue():String
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's only scoped **internal** in ActionScript. Also you could theoretically create new instances because you never check whether or not an instance was already created. You never double check.

I'd suggest avoiding singletons though. Similar to most iOC frameworks, you could have one context which creates the model. There you can create all instances and inject them via constructor or setter on a instance. That's a cleaner approach, because no one has to think about if a class must be used as a singelton or not. View controller could be created in such a context as well. Singletons are not really that useful imho.